# Finding the derivative of a vector?

Tags: calculus

How can one find the derivative of the following vector

$f(t)=e^{t}(i+tj+t^2k)$

I did the distributive property

$f(t)=e^t(i)+e^t(t)j+e^t(t^2)k$

then I took the derivative and got

$f'(t)=e^t(i)+(e^t(1)+(e^t)(t)(j))+(e^t(2t)+e^t(t^2)(k))$

but would this be correct?

Comment: Suggestion: use boldface for vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For vector-valued functions we take the derivative coordinate-wise.
However, you can simplify to 
$$ f'(t) = e^t(i+(1+t)j+(2t+t^2)k)$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec{r}(t)=x(t)\vec{i}+y(t)\vec{j}+z(t)\vec{k}$ and $x(t),y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are differentiable on $I$ then $$\vec{r'}(t)=x'(t)\vec{i}+y'(t)\vec{j}+z'(t)\vec{k}$$